# "fra loro" vs. "fra di loro"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> No, nessun problema al riguardo, gliela manutengono le donne—loro schiave—mentre fra *di* loro parlano della conquista dell'Occidente.

Secondo voi, cari amici, quel "di" lì è corretto o andrebbe scritto "fra loro"?

Se sono corrette entrambe le versioni, qual è la differenza?

Comment: Trovo insensata l'esistenza di “manutenere”;  non vedo problemi se *di* c'è o no.

Comment: @egreg In che senso sarebbe insensata l'esistenza di 'manutenere' lì?

Comment: Trovo che sia un verbo del tutto inutile, oltre che orribile.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In questo caso sono corrette entrambe le versioni e non hanno differenze significative, l'aggiunta del "di" è molto comune in italiano.

Answer (score 0):

In genere hanno lo stesso significato si può dire "fra loro non corre buon sangue o fra di loro non corre buon sangue"
Ma per essere più preciso l'uso della preposizione "di" dipende dalla situazione , si dice "fra loro" quando indica un elemento che si trova fra loro 
ad esempio: C'è un ragazzo tumultuoso che si siede fra loro. 
Fra i due edifici c'è un mercato.
Però si dice "fra di loro" quando si parla di un legame reciproco o un membro di un gruppo.
ad esempio: non erano d'accordo fra di loro ed era questo il punto. 
Scelsero un rappresentante fra di loro.